# creating a file in a specific directory bash

Tags: bash, shell

So basically i have a program that creates a file and a script file that in a directory  uses input from that file only prints the file's last line the problem is that the file is being created in its current directory and i want to it be created into a given one. To do that i used the mv command which isnt necessaraly creating in diferent directory its simply moving it which i dont want.

Problably what you will say is to change the program that creates the file the thing is that i cant.
I can only change the shell script file.

Program:

```
#!/bin/bash

inputdir="${1}"
outputdir="${2}"
maxthreads="${3}"
Ext=".txt"
prefix="$inputdir/"
for file in $(ls ${inputdir}/*.txt)
do
    filename=$(basename -- "$file" .txt)
    for i in $(seq 1 ${maxthreads})
    do
        echo "InputFile="${filename} "NumThreads="${i}
        outname="${filename}-${i}".txt
        # tecnicofs basically creates the out file
        ./tecnicofs ${file} ${outname} ${i} |sed '/^$/d'| awk NR | sort -nr| awk 'NR==1'
        mv ${outname} ${outputdir}
    done
done
```

As you can see in the end im moving the file to the output directory that i want, but like i said i want to move i want it to be created in the output directory so is there anyway to do this without creating in my current directory and moving it?

Comment: Why not just `out="${outputdir}/${filename}-${i}".txt` ?

Comment: actually because filename is the input file used in the tecnicofs program

Comment: This line needs a lot of work `./tecnicofs ${file} ${outname} ${i} |sed '/^$/d'| awk NR | sort -nr| awk 'NR==1'`. You don't need 5 processes to remove blank lines, count the remaining, sort numerically in reverse and then output the first line.. `sort -nr | head -n1` should do.